# penetration of Fe55 X-ray photons through glass

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, atomic-physics, radioactivity

Can X-ray photons from Fe55 (one radioactive isotope of iron) 
pass through glass ?

Comment: have you searched the net? http://www.ing.iac.es/~eng/detectors/QC/xray/xray.html  . "Most Xrays pass right through a thinned CCD. The 20% or so that are stopped are absorbed all depths throughout the silicon."  glass is silicon.

Comment: Look up the energy of the x-ray photons given off by Fe-55.  Find the mass attenuation coefficient of the glass in question or work it out on an elemental basis (there are many types of glass all with different compositions).  From there it will be easy to figure out how much transmission there will be through the glass you're interested in.

Comment: @annav - more properly, glass is mostly silicates. Plus various other oxides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decay produces the manganese K-alpha lines at 5.9 keV, see http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=260055

In SiO2, the attenuation length at 5.9 keV is about 50 microns, see http://henke.lbl.gov/optical_constants/atten2.html

[image]

Comment: So, Fe55  5.9 KeV X-ray photons can not pass through 2 mm thick SiO2 glass at all, if photons fall in perpendicular direction to the glass surface ; am I correct ?........Is there any formula/relation between (attenuation thickness of glass i.e. 0 to 100 %) & (photon energy) ?

Comment: @atom It is exponential. In this case $2$ mm of glass is about $40$ attenuation lengths, so transmission at this photon energy is $e^{-40} \approx 10^{-18}$ which is negligible.

Comment: How do you get e^-40 ?

Comment: @atom That is what the attenuation length means: where the intensity goes down to $1/e$ which is about $37$ %. Your $2$ mm of glass was $40$ times as thick, so the intensity is reduced by this factor $40$ times.